# ERROR 404: Not Found. while installing required dependencies in Ubuntu Server 20.04.2

Tags: software-installation, utorrent

- ```
  sudo apt install libssl-dev
  ```
- ```
  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
  ```
- ```
  sudo apt install ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
  ```

I use these command in my terminal to install utorrent dependency, first step is successful then error comes until later. Terminal shows:

```
root@serverpertama20042:/opt# wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3
_amd64.deb
--2021-07-09 14:04:09--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.88.152, 91.189.88.142, 2001:67c:1360:8001::23, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.88.152|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-07-09 14:04:15 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Because of that error, I can't move to third step eventhough I push it.
By the way, downloading 64 bit of utorrent and changing its directory is successful.

Comment: Are you following some tutorial/blog? And if you downloaded utorrent from https://www.utorrent.com/downloads/linux, I won't expecr that to work on 20.04 since latest version seems to be for 13.04.

Comment: yes, i follow two webs as my references

Comment: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-utorrent-ubuntu-20-04          https://lms.onnocenter.or.id/wiki/index.php/UTorrent:_Install_di_Ubuntu_20.04

Comment: linuxbabe says eventhough there is different version between utorrent and ubuntu server, it still can work

Comment: Yes. But they recommended using other client. Anyway libssl1.0 v5.3 and v5.5 ain't available presumabley because the release in which they were packed are now *dead*. You can try using v5.6 by running `wget https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb; sudo apt install ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb`.

Comment: I will try another version of Ubuntu Server. v5.6 showed connection refused and network is unreachable

Comment: Change `https` to `http`. I'm not sure why but `https` is refusing to connect on my side as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can still install UTserver by downloading [libssl from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libssl.so.1.0.0):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6_amd64.deb

wget https://download-hr.utorrent.com/track/beta/endpoint/utserver/os/linux-x64-debian-7-0 -O utserver.tar.gz
tar -xf utserver.tar.gz
cd utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3
./utserver
```

Then visit the web-interface at http://localhost:8080/gui, login using *admin* and empty password.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for other users for commenting, replying, helping me due to the problem. It works.

I also want to post my own answer.
Please give some notice to these commands!

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/*libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb*
sudo apt install ./*libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb*

The command which I put *italic* on it should be suitable and the newest version.
You can get its versions on this site:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/

Please use it wisely and be responsible!
Thank you.